# C# biggest of 5 numbers only with If/else

Tags: c#, if-statement, compare

While doing some C# exercises got stuck on this one.

// Finding the biggest of five numbers by using only **five** if statements.

I couldn't get how to make that, so I looked up online I set this up.

```
    Console.Write("Type number 1:");    double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Type number 2:");    double b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Type number 3:");    double c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Type number 4:");    double d = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Type number 5:");    double e = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    double max;
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a > e)
    {
        max = a;
        Console.WriteLine("The biggest number from {0} , {1} and {2} is {3}.", a, b, c, max);
    }
    else if (b > a && b > c && b > d && b > e)
    {
        max = b;
        Console.WriteLine("The biggest number from {0} , {1} and {2} is {3}.", a, b, c, max);
    }
    else if (c > a && c > b && c > d && c > e)
    {
        max = c;
        Console.WriteLine("The biggest number from {0} , {1} and {2} is {3}.", a, b, c, max);
    }
    else if (d > a && d > b && d > c && d > e)
    {
        max = d;
        Console.WriteLine("The biggest number from {0} , {1} and {2} is {3}.", a, b, c, max);
    }
    else
    {
        max = e;
        Console.WriteLine("The biggest number from {0} , {1} and {2} is {3}.", a, b, c, max);
    }
```

Using the exercise examples it returns correct data. For example

```
5   2   2   4   1   return: 5
```

But after further testing I ended up that it's wrong:

```
-1  -2  -2  -1  -15 return: -15
```

Either my first grade math skills are wrong or -15 isn't bigger than -1. I know where the mistake is but I don't know how to actually fix it.

Comment: I think you should use `>=` instead of `>`. Otherwise you have `false` for `-1 > -1`

Comment: And you always use `a, b, c, max` in your `Console.WriteLine`. And is there any special reason to parse your `string` to `double` not `int`?

Comment: Yes, that seems to works. I will do some more testing.

Comment: And if you have completed your studies use `double max = new[] { a, b, c, d, e }.Max();`.

Comment: Check this link > [C# program to find the largest of five number using else if](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/c-program-to-find-biggest-number-of.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle equality cases also, else no 'if' statement will match & you end up in the last 'else' block which sets `max=e`  which is wrong.
Do:

```
              if (a >= b && a >= c && a >= d && a >= e)
        {
            max = a;

        }
        else if (b >= a && b >= c && b >= d && b >= e)
        {
            max = b;

        }
        else if (c >= a && c >= b && c >= d && c >= e)
        {
            max = c;

        }
        else if (d >= a && d >= b && d >= c && d >= e)
        {
            max = d;

        }
        else
        {
            max = e;

        }
        Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Answer (score 6):

Quite easy even with only 4 if's.

```
double max = a;
if (b > max) max = b;
if (c > max) max = c;
if (d > max) max = d;
if (e > max) max = e;

Console.WriteLine("max is " + max);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's a possibility for ***cheating***, i.e.

```
  if (a > b)
    max = a;
  else
    max = b;
```

is equal to (*trenary operator*)

```
  max = a > b ? a : b;
```

of (*while loop emulation*)

```
  max = b;

  while (a > b) {
    max = a;

    break;
  }
```

Possible ***honest*** solution is straightforward and requies 4 `if`s only:

```
  ...
  Double max = a;

  if (max < b)
    max = b;

  if (max < c)
    max = c;

  if (max < d)
    max = d;

  if (max < e)
    max = e;

  Console.WriteLine("The biggest number from {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} is {5}.", a, b, c, d, e, max);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a smarter solution

```
    Console.Write("Type number 1:");    float a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Type number 2:");    float b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Type number 3:");    float c = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Type number 4:");    float d = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Type number 5:");    float e = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    float max = a;

    if (a < b)
    {
        max = b;
    }
    if (max < c)
    {
        max = c;
    }
    if (max < d)
    {
        max = d;
    }
    if (max < e)
    {
        max = e;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(max);
```

works fine.

Comment: This returns 15

`Type number 1:2
Type number 2:15
Type number 3:6
Type number 4:15
Type number 5:9
15
Press any key to continue . . .`

Answer (score 0):

i  know it is an old post but i just want to add my own solution to these.

```
int large = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter interger :");
            int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (num > large)
            {
                large = num;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(large);
```

Comment: You did not really answer the question. He asked for "Finding the biggest of five numbers by using only five if statements."

Comment: @yakobom,a best answer has already been ticked and am aware it is a five if statement solution,i just got interested in giving a simple solution even though am aware it cannot be used.The questions was asked three years ago,i was just adding alternatives

Comment: as a new user, you should be aware to the importance of answering the question. What you posted is an alternative for a different question - one without the constraints the user has specified.

Comment: as a new user, you should be aware to the importance of answering the question. What you posted is an alternative for a different question - one without the constraints the user has specified.